# Problema al abrir una nueva ventana con jQuery

Tags: jquery

he recibido este code para abrir ventanas con jQuery, que se abre cuando se pulsa el **Zoom icono**,

```
/**
 * Funcion que muestra las capas
 */
function layer_show()
{
    /* Ponemos los atributos de posicion a la capa transparente del fondo */
    $('#layerPreview').attr("style", "top:0px; height:"+$(document).height()+"px; width:"+$(window).width()+"px; display:inline;");

    /* Buscamos la posicion superior de la capa que aparece centrada.
       La anchura y la posicion centrada se establece en el estilo */
    var posTop=(($(window).height()/2)-(500/2))+$(document).scrollTop();
    if(posTop<0)
        posTop=0;
    $('#layerPreviewContent').attr("style", "top:"+posTop+"px;");
    /* Indicamos que se muestre la capa */
    $('#layerPreviewContent').show(600);
}

/**
 * Funcion que esconde las capas
 */
function layer_close()
{
    $('#layerPreviewContent').hide(300);
    $('#layerPreview').hide();
}
```

Css code que abre las ventana del jQuery Code,

```
/*      ***** Anfang    Fenster producut **** */


/* Determina el fondo transparente cuando se muestra la previsualizacion */
 #layerPreview      {position:absolute;z-index:1;display:none;top:  0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:#fff; 
                 background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);


}

 /* Determina la capa que aparecera centrada */
  #layerPreviewContent{position:absolute;z-index:1;display:none;background-color:#dedee0; margin-top: 0px;left:50%;
                width:30%;
                margin-left:-250px;
                height:40%;

                -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.6);
                -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.6);
                box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.6);


 }
 #tittel-text {padding: 3%; width:100%;text-align:left;border-bottom:1px hidden; background-color:  #d7a8a8;}
 #closse-text {  color: #f2f2f2; padding: 5px;  cursor: pointer; float: right;}


  /*  ------------------  */

#layerPreviewContent #bild-text img { 

  display: block; float: left; width: 42%; margin-top: 0px;  
}

#text-pruduct {   text-align: right; margin-top: 10%; margin-right: 5%;}

         /*  *****    ende    Fenster product ******  */
```

Y como he contruido las ventanas en Html,

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col"> 
         <div class="product-grid">
            <div class="product-image">
               <a class="link" href="/tachen_&_rucksacke/fenster/mochila_doble_tirantes-violeta.php">
                <img alt=""  class="bild" src="photo/112.jpg">     
               </a> 
            </div>
            <div class="product-content">
                 <a class="links" href="/tachen_&_rucksacke/fenster/mochila_doble_tirantes-violeta.php">
                <p class="title">Mochila doble tirantes Violeta</p>
                </a>     
            </div>
            <div class="price">$16.00</div>
               <div class="div-zoom">
                   <span class="zum-warenkorb">zum warenkorb hinzufügen</span>     

            /* Apartir de aquí empieza lo que llama a jQuery   */

             <i class="fa fa-search-plus" style="font-size: 94%; color: white; background-color:  #595959; padding: 3%; cursor: zoom-in;" onclick='layer_show();'></i></div> 

                 </div>
           </div> 



           <!-- En el momento que se pulse sobre la capa transparente se cerrara -->
                   <div id="layerPreview" > </div>
                   <div id='layerPreviewContent'>
                       <!-- Mostramos el texto de cerrar para poder cerrar la ventana -->
                      <div id="tittel-text">Rucksack aus Hanf Viola <span id="closse-text"  onclick="layer_close();">Schließen</span></div>
                      <div  id="bild-text"><img  alt=""  src="photo/112.jpg"></div>
                        <div id="text-pruduct">
                        <p>Verfügbarkeit: <b>eine Menge</b></p>
                        <p>Zustellung innerhalb von: <b>1-2 Tage</b></p>
                        <p>Hanf: <b>50%</b></p>
                        <p>Baumwolle: <b>50%</b></p> 
                      </div>
                   </div>
```

Come seve las ventanas,
[image: como seve la ventana]

[Aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/ichder/ky3t0pex/9/) todo el code...

El code funciona bien, el problema es que cuando en la segunda fotografia **clicko el Zoom**, recibo la primera fotografia(mochila violeta), en vez de la segunda fotografia(mochila amarilla) ,

```
 <div id="tittel-text">Rucksack aus Hanf amarillo <span id="closse-text"  onclick="layer_close();">Schließen</span></div>
                      <div  id="bild-text"><img  alt=""  src="photo/113.jpg"></div>
```

Pienso que el problema es como tengo el code, que no me da la posibilidad de hacer este cambio, me podria decir alguien porfavor como puede solucionar este problema, gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

al final la solución era mas facil de lo que parecia...la intente hace 4 dias pero no se porqué no funciono, y hoy sí...la solución es cambiar el nombre the todo los **id** que llamen al jQuery en el code **html**, como el nombre de las **funciones** que estan en el **jQuery** code...

```
**Html de la segunda venta** qué llaman al jQuery,

<i class="fa fa-search-plus" style="font-size: 94%; color: white; background-color:  #595959; padding: 3%; cursor: zoom-in;" onclick='layer_shows();'></i></div> 

                 </div>
           </div> 

                   <div id="layerPreview-2" > </div>
                   <div id='layerPreviewContent-2'>
                       <!-- Mostramos el texto de cerrar para poder cerrar la ventana -->
                      <div id="tittel-text">Rucksack aus Hanf Gelbe <span id="closse-text"  onclick="layer_closes();">Schließen</span></div>
                      <div  id="bild-text"><img  alt=""  src="photo/113.jpg"></div>
                        <div id="text-pruduct">
                        <p>Verfügbarkeit: <b>eine Menge</b></p>
                        <p>Zustellung innerhalb von: <b>1-2 Tage</b></p>
                        <p>Hanf: <b>50%</b></p>
                        <p>Baumwolle: <b>50%</b></p> 
                      </div>
                   </div>
```

El Style de él,

```
#layerPreview-2     {position:absolute;z-index:1;display:none;top: 0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:#fff; 
                 background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
}
#layerPreviewContent-2{position:absolute;z-index:1;display:none;background-color:#dedee0; margin-top: 0px;left:50%;
                width:30%;
                margin-left:-250px;
                height:40%;

                -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.6);
                -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.6);
                box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.6);
 }
 #layerPreviewContent-2 #bild-text img { 

   display: block; float: left; width: 42%; margin-top: 0px;  
 }
```

El jQuery de él,

```
function layer_shows()
{

    $('#layerPreview-2').attr("style", "top:0px; height:"+$(document).height()+"px; width:"+$(window).width()+"px; display:inline;");


    var posTop=(($(window).height()/2)-(500/2))+$(document).scrollTop();
    if(posTop<0)
        posTop=0;
    $('#layerPreviewContent-2').attr("style", "top:"+posTop+"px;");
    /* Indicamos que se muestre la capa */
    $('#layerPreviewContent-2').show(600);
}

function layer_closes()
{
    $('#layerPreviewContent-2').hide(300);
    $('#layerPreview-2').hide();
}
```

Como se ve la fotografia de la segunda ventana...

[image: como se ve la imagen]